# Telerik ASP.NET RadEditor and Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: asp.net, azure, telerik, azure-blob-storage, radeditor

I am using Telerik RadControls in a plain ASP.NET application. I tried different things to configure the file managers of a RadEditor control, like for example DocumentManager, but I can not get the thing working.

I looked online for any tutorial, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Is there anyone out there who has an Azure Blob Storage and successfully connected the RadEditor's DocumentManager to Upload and View url's to/from the Azure Blob Storage?

Any help, idea or even a lead is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: So the final solution was this:

I created a library using the code from http://azuretelerik.codeplex.com and added it as a reference to my project.

I also added the suggested config part (from the codeplex documentation page) into the webconfig.

I set up my storage accounts on azure and i made sure that i can read/write to it.

On the telerik RadEditor I added the path properties in the backend like this:

string[] _path = { "/" };

RadEditor1.DocumentManager.ViewPaths = path;
RadEditor1.DocumentManager.UploadPaths = path;

I hope this will help somebody else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one - http://azuretelerik.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: Just to update you, I'm trying to make this work, but so far no luck. I created a custom web app and added all the necessary things, but the loader just spins and spins without ever showing me the file upload/select window.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it working. :D I'll post back a longer process on how to achieve this so others don't need to mess around with it too much. Thanks a lot :)